# In Excel, Count rows returned from Filter function

Tags: sql, excel, filter

I am writing a formula that checks the overlap between Start and End time from DatabaseA and Start and End time from DatabaseB. I can confirm if overlap exists by doing the following:

```
DatabaseA Start Time > DatabaseB Start Time AND DatabaseA Start Time < DatabaseB End Time

Plus

DatabaseA End Time > DatabaseB Start Time AND DatabaseA End Time < DatabaseB End Time

Is Greater than 0
```

Now I need to find the exact number of overlap. So row 1 would say 5 instances of overlap, row 2 would say 2 instances of overlap. The issue with my current code is that it is susceptible to duplicate counts.

DataBase A Start Time (3:14) and End Time (3:16) could be completely engulfed within DataBase B Start Time (3:00) and End Time (3:56), and the way the formula is written it would return 2 instances of overlap even though it's just one overlap.

The I rewrote the formula with FILTER() so it functions with query logic, and I tested it. It works perfectly and the counts are awesome. The issue is that it returns a datafile instead of counts. Now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to count the rows returned from a Filter function. In SQL you would use something like COUNTROWS but I don't know if Excel has something similar.

Comment: how does your dataset + formula look like? anyways for others duplicate/try/test ur case?

Comment: A [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would make it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: I essentially just want a function I can wrap around a filter function to count rows returned by the filter function. I can produce a fake dataset, but I feel like there should be a function I can just wrap here.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, use the ROWS function to count the number of rows returned by the FILTER function. The syntax is as follows:

```
=ROWS(FILTER(array, include, [if_empty]))
```